# Binding grid to form without viewmodel

Tags: extjs, binding, extjs5

To binding between a grid and a form I use something like:

```
viewModel: {
    type: 'viewermodel'
},

items: [{
    xtype: 'grid',
    title: 'Grid: click on the grid rows',
    itemId:'myGridItemId',
    flex: 1.2,
    margin: '0 10 0 0',
    bind:{
        store:'{mystore}',
        selection:'{users}'
    },
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', flex:0.5 },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Cars', dataIndex: 'cars', flex: 1 }
    ]
},
```

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1is6&view/editor

Problem: the store is not in a viewmodel but in the store's app folder **(App.store.MyStore)**.

Is there any way, in this case, of binding selection: '{users}' from record grid to form fields? Something like:

```
store:'MyStore',
bind:{    
    selection:'{users}'
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add MyStore to your application's [store config](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/modern/Ext.app.Application.html#cfg-stores).

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1shc&view/editor). You'll see in Ext.application I've added `stores: ['MyStore']`

Comment: Thanks Jaimee for demonstrating that it is possible in this type of stores. This helps a lot. The store was declared. The problem will be elsewhere in the code. I'm going to have to review it again.